# Toggling menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I've got some HTML like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggle">[Open|Close]</a><a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2-4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

And would like that when the a with the class 'toggle' is clicked the ul will be toggled.  I am fairly decent with basic jQuery stuff, but have no real idea where to start with this one!  Any alternative approaches that achieve the same result would be welcome too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With that markup, this would work:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jQuery toggle function,
 http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle